# Ledit and derived terms

Tags: vocabulaire, étymologie

I searched for *ledit* (and derived terms such as *dudit*) here on FSE, and while I found questions and answers in which it was mentioned, I couldn't easily find anything on it specifically.

The meaning is transparent, but I'm interested in its origins. I've only encountered it in the odd archaic French book. The TLF mentions it under *dit* [here](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/dit/1). Unfortunately, the etymology lookup doesn't seem to mention it. It's also on [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ledit) but without much of a history.

How, when, and where did these forms come about? Are they still in use, and if so in what contexts? (I notice that some dictionaries, including those indexed [on the DVLF](https://dvlf.uchicago.edu/mot/ledit), don't have them, at least not under *ledit*.) If not, when did they disappear? Has anything replaced them?

*Edit:* Laure observes that [French Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ledit) does include an etymology. There it's said that these two words were "grammaticalized", not merely run together in the spelling. Yet to my eyes the sentences parse the same as if they were written with *le dit*, etc. Why might the words have been run together? Does it reflect a different underlying parsing or is it just a quirk that's never been smoothed out?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57901/discussion-on-question-by-luke-sawczak-ledit-and-derived-terms).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Le *Dictionnaire historique de la langue française* signale le premier emploi de *dit* (participe passé de dire) avec le sens de *nommé, indiqué* en 1219 mais ne donne aucun exemple et à cette heure je n'en ai pas trouvé. C'est à partir de cet usage du mot comme adjectif qu'ont été forgés les adjectifs (démonstratif) *ledit* et *susdit* à partir du XV<sup>e</sup> siècle (selon le Wiktionnaire et je n'ai pas trouvé d'autres références).

Grevisse (*Le bon usage*, 10<sup>e</sup> édition, § 775) remarque que « le participe passé *dit* se soude avec l'article défini et avec l'adverbe *sus*, surtout en termes de procédure ou d'administration, dans des expressions employées pour dire qu'il a déjà été question de personnes ou des choses dont il s'agit... » :

> - Le fondateur dudit journal (Balzac, *La peau de chagrin*)
> - Le premier jour de mai de ladite année (A. France, *L'île des pingouins*)

Dans un *nota bene* il note qu'« on s'affranchit souvent de cet usage, qui n'est d'ailleurs fondé sur aucune raison grammaticale, et qui est devenu, comme le suppose Littré, par imitation de monsieur, madame, etc. »

> - Déballage du dit berceau (Chateaubriand, *Mémoires* III)
> - Le secrétaire des dits journaux (J. et J. Tharaud, *Notre cher Péguy*).

Grevisse se contente de décrire l'usage sans prendre partie, par contre Bruno Dewaele du *Projet Voltaire*, dans sont entrée [*« le dit » ou « ledit » ?*](https://www.projet-voltaire.fr/regles-orthographe/le-dit-ou-ledit/) considère que la règle est d'écrire « en un seul mot les termes composés d’un article et de « dit » ou de « dite ». » et que c'est une erreur de les écire en deux mots.

Comme le signale jlliagre dans sa réponse ces formes se trouvent essentiellement dans des textes juridiques et actes notariés, mais peuvent se rencontrer, et encore de nos jours, dans d'autres genres d'écrits :

> - Le propriétaire de ladite boîte a été entendu par la police. (Nord Éclair du [26/04/2017](http://www.nordeclair.fr/55150/article/2017-04-26/la-station-de-metro-tourcoing-centre-evacuee-lundi-soir))
> - la saison 3 de Young Justice, réclamée à corps et à cri, sera elle-aussi diffusée sur ladite plateforme (*Comics blog*, [26/04/2017](http://www.comicsblog.fr/26983-DC_Comics_annonce_une_srie_live_Teen_Titans_et_la_diffusion_de_Young_Justice_saison_3))
> - cette histoire de radiation des listes électorales, qui a empêché 2000 Strasbourgeois environ d'accomplir leur devoir électoral, ne fait pas grogner que lesdits électeurs. (L'Alsace.fr [26/04/2017](http://www.lalsace.fr/politique/2017/04/25/radiation-des-listes-electorales-clash-entre-un-adjoint-et-un-depute-ps))

Une recherche dans la presse écrite montre quand même que l'emploi de [ledit](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=ledit&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cledit%3B%2Cc0) et ses dérivés ([ladite](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=ladite&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cladite%3B%2Cc0), [lesdits](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=lesdites&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Clesdites%3B%2Cc0)) est en perte de vitesse et que les renvois sont essentiellement vers des écrits historiques et juridiques. Et si on peut en trouver dans la presse ou des écrits universitaires c'est tout de même plus rare dans des romans.

Answer (score 2):

All these forms are still well known and in use, especially but not only in formal/written administrative and judicial contexts.

The aggregation of the article is very old and makes their etymology quite clear, here *ledit* means "the said", i.e. the person/thing named.

*Ledit* might be replaced by *en question*:

> Ledit voisin = Le voisin en question

Comment: Premiers emplois adjectivés de *dit* dans le sens de *surnommé*, *indiqué* au 13 s. (DHLF).

Comment: If these dates are incorporated into the answer, I'll accept it straightaway. I think the heart of my question, which didn't come through now that I reread it, consists in my finding the forms bizarre. How and why did they come to be written as one? As the Projet Voltaire page mentions, one wants to recall that *dit* is an adjective and write them separately. As one word they suggest an overgrown determiner... was there a different parsing? Or was its running together merely the inconsistent orthography of an earlier age (yet never corrected by the venerable Académie)?

Comment: These words are not the only example where two elements were joined in the past but still keep an inner agreement. See *bonhomme/bonshommes*, *monsieur/messieurs*, *monseigneur/messeigneurs*, *madame/mesdames*, *mademoiselle/mesdemoiselles*, *gentilhomme/gentilshommes*, *lequel/laquelle/lesquels/lesquelles*, *duquel/desquels*, *auquel/auxquelles*.

Comment: not only?  this screams bureaucracy, and especially legalese.  Please don't ever use it orally.

Comment: I once read in a book that even communication professionals (TV & radio hosts) had a hard time keeping up with the gender & number of _lequel_ and frequently fall back to the singular masculine form. My own observations following this information showed it was at least partly true, with a couple mistakes noticed every week on Radio-Canada. But I think they're useful words and don't see any particular reason to work on avoiding them when they naturally show up as the logical way to express what one wants to say.